# Regex to remove leading character if target exists otherwise return the whole line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ and need a regular expression to remove all characters before a target if it exists.  Some lines wont have the target at all in which case I want to leave the line unchanged.

```
In this example lets use a "<" character:

This line doesn't have one
This line does <keep>
This line also <and we'll keep all this
This line doesn't either
This line <has two< in it

Results:

This line doesn't have one
<keep>
<and we'll keep all this
This line doesn't either
<has two< in it
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So where are you stuck at your attempt to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*?(<.*)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : beginig of line
.*?     : 0 or more any character, not greedy
(<.*)   : group 1, '<' followed by 0 or more any character
$       : end of line
```

- DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`

**Result for given example:**

```
This line doesn't have one
<keep>
<and we'll keep all this
This line doesn't either
<has two< in it
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/^.*?(?=<)/m` with substitution.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dygo7l/1/)